# PHP-FPM, Nginx - process manager details not showing up in phpinfo()

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am running PHP7.0-FPM with Nginx 1.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I used to be able to see the "Process Manager" details in phpinfo() - this included things I customized like:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

I edited these entries (uncommented them) in:
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

Now these entries are not showing up in phpinfo(), even though I'm pretty sure they used to show up.  I'm not sure what I did for them to disappear.  It does say "php-fpm active" in phpinfo(), but that is about as close as it gets to anything related to "Process Manager" in phpinfo().

I'm guessing process manager is still working, but I'm not sure with what settings since they aren't showing up in phpinfo().

Is this true?  Why wouldn't they be showing up?  It is definitely reading in the /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file.

Please help!